# Two passports for travel between Russia, the UK and the Netherlands

Tags: visas, passports, schengen-visas, standard-visitor-visas

I am a citizen of Russia. Our regulations allow us to have two valid Russian passports (for travel to other countries) at the same time. Currently I have two valid Russian passports:

- passport #1 contains a multiple-entry Schengen visa,
- passport #2 contains the UK Standard Visitor visa.

I am going to visit the UK and the Netherlands:

- flight #1: Moscow - London,
- flight #2: London - Amsterdam,
- flight #3: Amsterdam - Moscow.

I will obviously use passport #2 for flight #1, and passport #1 for flight #3. What I don't know is which passport I should use for flight #2. If I use passport #1, the UK Home Office will probably not see that I have left the UK (simply because I will use different passports when entering and leaving the UK, and air companies share travel data with the Home Office). If I use passport #2, then I will probably have some trouble when entering the Netherlands (because a Schengen visa is not in this passport).

Could you please tell me what I should do in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use both passports.  Present passport #2, explaining that you used it to enter the UK so it should be sent to the UK government with the passenger manifest so they can record your entry properly.  Also show passport #1 and the visa that it contains to show that you are authorized to fly to the Schengen area.

If the airline can't handle this and insists on entering passport #1 only, don't worry too much about it.  You can set the record straight by showing what happened the next time you go to the UK, for example by bringing both passports.

When you arrive in the Netherlands, of course, you will present the passport containing the Schengen visa.  You can do this even if you never showed it to the airline.  If by some chance they notice that the passport number doesn't match, you can also show the other passport.  There's no reason not to show both.

Comment: `There's no reason not to show both.` especially because people are normally afraid to do this when they are dual citizens for whatever reasons they have, whereas in this case, it's single citizenship but just two valid active passports, no reason to be afraid from showing them both!

Comment: @kiradotee indeed, reluctance to show both seems more likely to arouse suspicion as it might be taken as a desire to hide something.